# Latency and number of FMA units

Tags: c++, intel, simd, micro-optimization, fma

I'm trying to implement the convolution algoritm descibed in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.10170.pdf). The authors state that the number of independent elements processed by FMA instructions is lower bounded by the latency of FMA istructions and it is upper bounded by the number/width of vector registers in the following way:

```
N_vec * N_fma * L_fma < X < N_reg * N_vec
```

Where:

- N_vec: Number of elements contained in a vector register
- N_reg: Number of vector registers
- N_fma: Number of FMA units
- L_fma: Latency of one FMA instruction

I'm using an Intel Core i7-10510U, and I set the parameters as follow:

| NAME | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| N_vec | 8 |
| N_reg | 16 |
| N_fma | 2 |
| L_fma | 4 |

This is motivated by the following reasons: I'm using 256b registers (N_reg=16). I'm using 4B single precision floating point data (N_vec=8).
My question is about the latency and the number of FMA units. From [Intel Intrisic guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=_mm256_fma&ig_expand=3202) I see that on my architecture (i.e., Skylake) the _mm256_fmadd_ps instruction has a throughput of 0.5 (cycle/instructions) and a latency of 4 cycles.
For this reason I assumed to have 2 FMA units.

By doing so I obtaing the bounds for X:

```
(8 * 2 * 4) < X < (16 * 8) => 64 < X < 128
```

However, by running some experiments, I see that the execution time is shorter when I use X=256 or X=512.

Am I getting any of the above parameters wrong? Especially N_fma and L_fma

Comment: How much shorter is your execution time?  Using only just barely the number of parallel operations to hide FP latency means any imperfect scheduling loses a cycle on a dependency chain, and the latency bottleneck means you can't catch back up.  See [Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables? (Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45113527) for some experiments with number of accumulators for an FP dot-product on Skylake.

Comment: Note also that saturating FMA leaves for example only one port for jump & branch. Any extraneous code at all can easily knock things sideways.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks a lot for useful answer and references. The execution time in such cases is about  10% shorter. After reading your references I removed the constraints on X and I applied 8 loop unrolling (Intel compiler appies by itself 4 loop unrolling). Now performance is much better, but this contradicts what is said in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.10170.pdf).

Comment: Tuning source-code is compiler-dependent.  I haven't read that paper, but maybe they were experimenting with a different one.  Have you checked the resulting asm to see if there are a lot of store/reload of vectors to stack space (which would be a sign of running out of registers)?  If the asm isn't too much of a mess, you might be able to figure out how many times the loop is unrolled (perhaps from finding a pointer-increment instruction)